# Postgresql Idle connections

Tags: postgresql

i am seeing a lot of idle connections in `pg_stat_activity` and want these to be closed automatically after 5 min. i have set below configuration in `postgresql.conf` file
`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 300000`

but it doesn't seem to work. i am still seeing idle connections. below is a screen shot of connections

**Query**

`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname= 'db_name'`

[image]

Comment: `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` only kills session that are `idle in transaction`. It does not affect sessions that are `idle`

Comment: 1) **DO NOT** use images, copy and paste the text into your question. 2)  a) Close the connections on the client end. b) Use a connection pool to deal with high client load.  c) Use [idle_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html), read docs for caveats on this setting.

Comment: thank you for the comment, it looks like `idle_session_timeout` is what i was looking for. @AdrianKlaver can you please tell why i can't put picture here, it made more sense to take an ss of the table rather than copy pasting it .

Comment: 1) You have to enlarge the image to see anything useful which takes you away from the question. 2) You cannot copy and paste examples from the image to use in an explanation 3) See here [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Do not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for more reasons. Bottom line if you use images many people will ignore the question and/or down vote it.